# Why does the lighting on my walls look funny? Three.js

Tags: three.js

In my game that uses Three.js (r52)  I'm having some trouble getting the lighting right.

This dungeon level uses simple cuboids as the walls and the roof. For some reason the lighting is bright at the beginning of each mesh, but then fades to dark towards the other side.

Notice that the floor doesn't have artifacts, this is because it is one huge quad.
[image]

The light used is a PointLight. The materials for my meshes are simply created like this:

```
   var texture  = new THREE.Texture( image,
    new THREE.UVMapping(),
    THREE.RepeatWrapping,
    THREE.RepeatWrapping,
    THREE.NearestFilter,
    THREE.NearestMipMapLinearFilter );

  return new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    map : texture
  });
```

The cuboids are exported OBJ models from 3ds max, converted using gw::OBJ-exporter. These are my export settings:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you hit the same issue as in this thread: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1258

You need to use something like material.shading = THREE.FlatShading;

Comment: Well, actually, you asked "Why?". The reason is that the vertex normals at the _left edge_ of the face of your cube are not parallel to the vertex normals at the _right edge_ of the face of your cube. Hence, there is a discontinuity at the seam where two cubes meet. Using THREE.FlatShading ignores the vertex normals and uses the face normal in the lighting calculation instead. If your vertex normals were parallel, you would not have seen this artifact.